# Cannot import name 'RemoteZip' from partially initialized module 'remotezip'

Tags: python

I am using remotezip to download a file from a zip file so that I can save my computer disk space. I follow this instructions of usage: https://pypi.org/project/remotezip/
Here is my code:

```
from remotezip import RemoteZip

with RemoteZip('http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2021SpringFCS/fullrestores/071-45307/56662841-0D2D-4F77-A7F3-D0D8B1061625/iPhone_4.7_P3_14.6_18F72_Restore.ipsw') as zip:
    zip.extract('018-18125-090.dmg')
```

And I received this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'RemoteZip' from partially initialized module 'remotezip' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also happen if you name the python file with the same name as the library that your project uses. That is,
You can't have a file named `remotezip.py`. This means using a batch of retries. Just rename the file, for example, like this: `myfile_remotezip_1.py`

Answer (score 0):

it is maybe more a guess than a solution but did you name your module or the package remotezip? in that case it might  shadow the lib